# Get the parent node element

Tags: jquery

I need to get the parent node of ths child node

this is my current code

```
console.log (($(editor.selection.getNode()).parent()[0]));
```

this returns some thing like this

```
<ol>....</ol>
```

but what i need is to catch the Ol element only

so any one can help with ?

Comment: can you show us your HTML pls?

Comment: @Chanmz "i need is to catch the Ol element only" means?

Comment: sounds like the same thing... `ol element only` and `<ol>...</ol>`

Comment: Right now, what you **caught**?

Comment: that seems fine, when it logs in the console, it also prints the children

Comment: Sorry about the less details guys , What Im getting is html string in console log ya , So what I need is only the ol tag . hope Im clear about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying get the tag name. You can get the tag name from an element using the tagName property. try this

```
console.log (($(editor.selection.getNode()).parent()[0].tagName));
```

Answer (score 0):

## **HTML**

```
<ol id="h1">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>II</li>
</ol>
<ol id="h2">
    <li>I</li>
    <li>II</li>
</ol>
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function(){
        alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/SB659/

Reference http://api.jquery.com/parent/